# AHK help. Is there anyway to make this more efficient?

Tags: autohotkey

A little background, the script finds an image in a window then presses the corresponding key to execute a command in that active window. It does the job but makes me lag a little. Right now it has to progress through the lines one at a time which can take up to 1.5 to 2 seconds per loop. Is there a way to have the script look for all the images at once? Then when it recognizes one of the images to Send the corresponding key to the window. I rather the script be faster and more reliable. Any tips on the organization side will be much appreciated aswell. Here is my code so far.

```
  IfWinActive, xx{
Loop
{
    CoordMode, Pixel, Window
    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, C:\retreat_F.png
    If ErrorLevel = 0
    {
        Send, {f}
    }
    CoordMode, Pixel, Window
    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *5 C:\knee_F.png
    If ErrorLevel = 0
    {
        Send, {f}
    }
    CoordMode, Pixel, Window
    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, C:mighty_cleave_F.png
    If ErrorLevel = 0
    {
        Send, {f}
    }
    CoordMode, Pixel, Window
    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *7 C:\uppercut_4.png
    If ErrorLevel = 0
    {
        Send, {4}
    }
    CoordMode, Pixel, Window
    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, *5 C:\piledrive_F.png
    If ErrorLevel = 0
    {
        Send, {f}
    }
    CoordMode, Pixel, Window
    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, C:\moltenkup_C.png
    If ErrorLevel = 0
    {
        Send, {c 2}
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Any clues as to what you are trying to do please?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated the post. The script finds an image in a window then presses the corresponding key to execute a command in that active window.

Comment: Can more than one image be in a window? If not, you can return as soon as you have found one instead of always looking for all of them. Is there one image that is more likely to be present, if so, look for that one first.

Comment: If your script is scanning the whole monitor screen you can reduce the scanned area to fit the target's window zone (if your application isn't fullscreen).

Answer (score 0):

You can make the code much shorter - you do the same thing each time, just with different parameters. Put the parameters in an array and use a loop:
You are also calling `CoordMode` every time, and you do not need to.

```
#SingleInstance force
#Persistent

mappings := [{imgsearch: "C:\retreat_F.png", send: "{f}"}
            ,{imgsearch: "*5 C:\knee_F.png", send: "{f}"}
            ,{imgsearch: "C:mighty_cleave_F.png", send: "{f}"}
            ,{imgsearch: "C:\moltenkup_C.png", send: "{c 2}"}]

CoordMode, Pixel, Window    ; You only need this once, since you do not change mode
;IfWinActive, xx{
Loop
{
    for i, mapping in mappings {
        ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, % mapping.imgsearch
        If ErrorLevel = 0
        {
            Send, % mapping.send
        }
    }
    Sleep 10    ; You should probably have a sleep in your loop to avoid high CPU usage
}
;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing ImageSearch with the custom function [Gdip_ImageSearch](https://github.com/MasterFocus/AutoHotkey/tree/master/Functions/Gdip_ImageSearch).

ImageSearch recaptures the image each time, whilst Gdip_ImageSearch doesn't.

Thus using Gdip_ImageSearch should reduce lag.